# Why does the instruction "do" require a "while"?

Tags: java, c, loops, multithreading

Since this statement is so common:

`while (true)` (Java)

or

`while (1)` (C)

or sometimes

`for (;;)`

Why is there not a single instruction for this? I could think that an instruction that could do it is just `do` but `do` requires a `while` at the end of the block but it would be more logical to write an infinite loop like this

```
do {

//loop forever

}
```

Why not? AFAIK the instruction `do` always requires a `while` at the end but if we could use it like above then it would be a clear way to define something like `while (true)` which I think should not be written like that (or `for (;;)`).

Comment: what about the word "do" implies an infinite loop?

Comment: What we're trying to program in an instuction that does `do forever`and I think that could be just `do { ... }` but that is mostly not allowed.

Comment: If someone were going to add a statement like this, a better choice would be `forever`.  Doesn't really matter, though, because `forever {...}` and `while (true) {...}` are going to compile down to the same code anyway.

Comment: `#define forever while(true)`

Comment: `#undef forever` and just use `while (true)`. No need to be creative.

Comment: A missing trailing `while (...)` is _far_ more likely to be an error than it is an intended infinite loop. Allowing it would be silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is largely because creating a separate command **would be unnecessary**.  Adding extra, unneeded commands to a programming language is often considered poor design.  Why create a special instruction when one already exists that works?

Your idea of having only one of the "do/while" pair **is how it works in other languages**, like *Python*, for instance, since Python doesn't having closing brackets to worry about.

```
while True:
    ...
```

It is simply a matter of how any **given language** is **designed**.  Remember that programming languages are man-made things - they can take **whatever form we, as humans, design** them to take.  You could make your own language that follows the principle you desire, if you felt it was important enough.

Comment: your python example doesn't match the purpose of `do{}while()`. The idea behind `do{}while()` is checking the condition at the end of the loop, not at the beginning.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think you misunderstand the question.  The original poster is asking about creating an intentionally infinite loop, and why a conditional is necessary at all in such a common structure, whether at the beginning or end.

Comment: The two part `do...while` only exists to check after the loop. For checking at the beginning and infinite loops c doesn't require a pair either. There is no difference as far as this question is concerned between python's `while True:` and c's `while(true)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos ...exactly.  That's the point.  This is as simple as the statement gets.

Comment: Java and C can do this code too. It's not unique to Python. I'm not sure what point you're tying to make.

Answer (score 4):

Programming languages are still languages, and when translating code from English to programming language X, you may have to change some idioms, reorder words, sentences, or sometimes include unpronounceable curly braces…

When you want an infinite loop, the `while (true)` or its equivalents can be used. Without good reasons, no language designer will add yet another keyword just for infinite loops.

Your idea that `do { ... }` always implies a trailing `while ...` doesn't hold up. In Ruby, `do` starts a code block, and in Perl it allows you to use a code block on expression level:

```perl
# read a whole file at once
my $file_contents = do {
  local $/;
  open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
  <$fh>;
};
```

Because `do` is always an expression, various other statement modifers may be used as well (`if`, `unless`, and special-cased keywords to evaluate the block once before testing the condition: `while` and `until`).

Perl6 is interesting here because it renames the C-style `for` to the `loop` keyword. The various statements like initialization are optional, so one can write:

```
loop {
  say "hi";
}
```

… which is the same as `say "hi" while True`.

---

Just use `while (true)` – everyone will understand that. The `for(;;)` is also a widely-understood *idiom*. If you are using a language with a preprocessor, you could also do evil stuff like `#define forever for(;;)`, but that reduces maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that language designers care somewhat about helping developers write accurate code. A language may prefer to not introduce a construct that leads to an infinite loop without the developer explicitly request it. A language like REXX take this concept further and introduces a forever loop as in:

```
do forever
...
end
```

So, to answer your question the reasons may be:

1. To help developers write better code.
2. To be similar to other popular languages.
3. To use a single construct instead of several.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that do while is more explicit than just do. In programming it's often beneficial to be explicit. This translates into code that is easier to read. With the proposed do loop the while(true) portion or condition is still implied.

So to sum it all up I'd say it's because most languages are designed to be explicit and readable.

Answer (score 1):

`do/while` is semantically different from `for` and `while` in that the condition is checked *after* the loop body has executed, not before.  The `do { ... } while(condition)` structure makes that behavior clear.  Now, dmr *could* have used a different method to convey the same semantics, like

```
until ( condition ) { ... }
```

but it isn't as clear (to me, anyway) that `condition` is evaluated at the *end* of the loop.

For an infinite loop it doesn't matter; just use `for(;;)` (which I think is more idiomatic than `while(1)`).

Comment: What you wrote looks like repeat-until loops in Pascal and Lua. The loop has an *exit condition* at the end of the loop instead of an *entry condition* at the start.

Answer (score 1):

What should be the meaning of:

```
do
{
  doThis();
  doThat();
  if(shouldExit())
    break();
  theOtherThing();
}
while(read_data() != null)
  ;
```

If some other keyword had been used for expressing the continuation condition of a `do` loop (as with Pascal's `Repeat`...`Until`) then it might have been possible to make the continuation condition optional.  As it is, however, `while(condition);` can either appear as the last thing in a `do`/`while` or as a stand-alone loop.  *Something* must appear between the controlled statement of a do/while and a succeeding stand-alone statement, and its easiest to simply have that `something` always be a `while(expr);` clause.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: for no specific reason other than personal tastes of the language designers.

Some languages, such as PL/SQL, Ada, Common Lisp, Perl6 and Go (as amon and topskip have demonstrated) do have a loop structure that loops infinitely when used by itself, but can be optionally extended with several clauses, such as while, until, initialization, increments, etc.

Most likely the C designers thought that for+while+do/while were the most useful idioms and then C++, Java and others just copied the loop statements, preferring to focus their design efforts on other language features, such as object orientation.

In other words, I don't think language designers think that's a bad feature, it's just that eventually you have to stop adding features, and there's a solid tradition in C-based languages to have for+while+do/while. In other languages, the feature you suggested does exist and it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
there:
    ........
    goto there;
```

But really "while(true)" is clear and concise.

A naked "while" is ambiguous, why should it mean loop forever. Logically its "while nothing" which  implies you never go there.

Similarly a naked "do" would imply "do once". If someone asks you to "do the dishes" you wash them once, you do not wash them over and over again until someone asks you to stop.

Perhaps more importantly an infinite loop is an important thing to notice if you are trying to understand a programs logic, it should have a noticeable syntax and
not a single word easily passed over.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loops are generally regarded as bad pratcice, and thus it wouldn't make sense to include a dedicated syntax for them in a language. Special syntax (or 'syntatic sugar') is added for common tasks, such as an `unless` block in addition to an `if` block, to make the code more 'friendly' and readable.

Since infinite loops are fairly rare, and are generally regarded as bad practice, it wouldn't be a good idea to support them in a language via a dedicated syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view using do...while to create infinite loops leads to code difficult to maintain. When you encounter a do you have to scroll all the way to see if it is a infinite loop or not. On the other hand using for(;;) or while(1) at the beginning of the loop is a lot more clear. As it was already mentioned you can still create infinite loops with the current design of the language so you don't need to change it. Since there is no actual need for a design change in the language none is actually changing it.